# Meta Stack Exchange newsletter is not delivered on December 25

Tags: support, newsletter

I used to receive the Meta Stack Exchange newsletter on every Tuesday. I didn't receive the newsletter for this Tuesday (December 25, 2018).

I have verified in junk/spam folders too, seems it is not delivered to me. I'm the only person not received the newsletter, or it is not sent to everyone?